# JavaScript return false form validation not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, return

Can you help me, when the validation fails my script should unhide an error message in a p tag and return false but instead my form submits. Can you see where my problem is?

```
function validate() {
if (document.emailForm.EMAIL_ADDRESS_.value.length==0) {
    $('#errorNoAddress').fadeIn();
    return false;
}
if (document.emailForm.EMAIL_ADDRESS_.value.length>0) {
   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   var address = document.emailForm.email.value;
   if(reg.test(address) == false) {
      $('#errorInvalidAddress').fadeIn();
      return false;
   }
}
document.emailForm.submit();
return true;
}

<form id="emailForm" name="emailForm" action="http://domain.com/formhandler.php" method="post">
    <p id="errorNoAddress" class="error">Please enter an e-mail address.</p>
    <p id="errorInvalidAddress" class="error">Please enter a valid email address.</p>
    <label for="EMAIL_ADDRESS_">E-mail</label>

    <input type="hidden" id="QUICK_SIGN_UP"  name="QUICK_SIGN_UP" value="" />
    <input type="image" src="btn-submit.gif" value="Submit" onclick="validate();" />
</form>
```

Comment: do you "submit" the form by hitting return or by clicking the button? cause you only catch clicking the button, hitting return would still directly submit the form.

EDIT: oh and you shouldn't return true after submitting, as some browsers may think your script is still doing something.

Comment: You click the button to submit, but potentially users will also hit return.

Comment: if it does submit after entering a wrong email and clicking the button, your checks don't work correctly. if it does (always) submit after pressing return, you have to intercept the `form.onSubmit` event.

Comment: removing return true and adding return before the validate function in the onclick seem to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

try `<input type="image" src="btn-submit.gif" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();" />`